# `insertBefore()` or `insertAfter()` deletes the element when the origin and the destination are the same

Tags: javascript, jquery

It looks like when `insertBefore()` or `insertAfter()` has the same element as the origin and the destination, the element is deleted. Is my understanding correct?

```
$('#foo').insertBefore($('#foo'))
```

Is this a feature? If so, what other gotchas are there with these functions?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @SalmanA The expected result is there to be no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually seems that it is a [known bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4087) (not a feature), although there may be an incoming fix (1.9 release).

From the bug comments:

> Since jQuery.domManip passes in a fragment, jQuery.clean moves #x to
>   the fragment. Later when it gets to the callback in jQuery.after, the
>   original parentNode is gone.

Comment: Looks as though the fix was committed and merged in with the jQuery 1.9 release: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/f12611feb43adb2b014eb2183db0713451746aff

Comment: Yeah, I should have made that more clear in my post, I'll add that.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will get the newer version when it becomes available.

Comment: You can build your own following the steps outlined in the README here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/1.9-stable or, just include the changes from the relevant commit, [f12611f](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/f12611feb43adb2b014eb2183db0713451746aff), and merge them into your copy.

Comment: You can also download betas and release candidates from the blog: http://blog.jquery.com/

Answer (score 9):

This is because `insertBefore` and `insertAfter` remove an element and move it. Once you've removed the element it no longer exists for the origin element to be inserted before (or after). To achieve the cloning effect you might be looking for, try:

`$('#foo').clone().insertBefore($('#foo'))`

Comment: +1 for the diagnosis. Might want to deal with that duplicate ID value, though, in your `clone` example.

Comment: True. Not really the question, however.

Comment: If you do the same in vanilla JS, the browser will throw a *hierarchy request* error. The operation should be forbidden, however jQuery suppresses this error and executes the first half of the operation (removing the element).

Comment: @David: Yeah, just caught that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `insertBefore()` and `insertafter()` *moves* the element from the source position to the destination position. If you want to insert a clone instead, you can use:

```
$('#foo').clone().insertBefore($('#foo'))
```

But note that the clone will have the same ID, something you don't want. So change the id after cloning it, but before inserting.

i.e. something like:

```
$('#foo').clone().attr('id', 'foo2').insertBefore($('#foo'))
```

Comment: While true, that's not the crux of the OP's issue.